# Url Rewrite in Magento

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting

Im trying to add Url rewrites in my `magento store`, Enabling it from configuration is not working.

- How to setup Url Rewrites in Magento.?
- Do I need to manually change all the url keys of thousands of products in my store.?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-url-rewrites

Comment: Do i need to creaate rewrite for every product?

Comment: There are various extensions which will allow you to bulk upload via CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this extension for free provided by Inchoo -

> https://github.com/ajzele/Inchoo_UrlRewriteImporter

This extension will enable you to bulk import URL rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

No, after creating and product or category magento automatically creates url-key for the same.
You can create it by indexing also.

And if there is any issue with url keys then use following steps

- Go to database
- Take backup of **url_rewrite** table
- truncate the table
- Reindex from index management.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly the answer for your question since it depends on the rule you are going to apply for your products's URLs.

Hope the following information can help:

- Each Magento Product has a URL-key as an attribute of product. You
  can see it in **Edit Product** area.
- These keys are also **indexed**
  for routing purpose, and you can see all rewrite rules in **URL Rewrite**
  area.